# Disable twitter typeahead.js cache

Tags: typeahead.js

I'm having some problems with typeahead.js cache. This is the code I'm using:

```
$('#descripcionArticulo').typeahead({
            name: 'descripcionarticulotypeahead',
            remote: '@Url.Action("GetArticulos", "NotaPedido", new { Area = "Ventas" })?q=%QUERY&limit=20',
            minLength: 2,
            limit: 20,
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            template: [
                '<span class="repo-name">{{value}}</span>'
            ].join(''),
            prefetch: {
                ttl: 1
            },
            engine: Hogan
        }).on("typeahead:selected", function (res, data) {
            dialogDetalleModel.loadArticulo(data);
        }).on("typeahead:opened", function(event, ui) {
            $('#descripcionArticulo').typeahead('setQuery', $('#descripcionArticulo').val()); 
        });
```

Does anyone know the option to disable cache?

Answer (score 1):

add the key/value `cache:false` to your prefetch object.

But aren't you mixing typeahead and bloundhound initialization and code ?

Comment: Ok that's a serious dig'up >_<

Comment: Thanks for your help Tryum! tried that approach previously but didn't work. I decided to modify the typeahead library, which isn't the better approach, but at least works :)